# create a manual legend for density plots in R (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, density-plot

I want to add a legend to my graph. All solutions I found online use scale_color_manual - but it's not working for me. Where is the legend?
Here is my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = rnorm(100)), color = 'red') +
  geom_density(aes(x = rnorm(100)), color = 'blue') +
  xlab("Age") + ylab("Density") + ggtitle('Age Densities')
  theme(legend.position = 'right') +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c('first', 'second'), values = c('red', 'blue'))
```

Comment: BTW, in my real case, the lengths of the 2 vectors whose density I am plotting are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If for some reason you absolutely need the two geoms to take on different data sources, move the `color = XXX` portion inside `aes()` for each, then define the colors manually using a named vector:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_density(aes(x = rnorm(100), color = 'first')) +
  geom_density(aes(x = rnorm(100), color = 'second')) +
  xlab("Age") + ylab("Density") + ggtitle('Age Densities') +
  theme(legend.position = 'right') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('first' = 'red', 'second' = 'blue'))
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Thank you very much - this is an excellent solution (and a great learning)! 
I did not realize one could use 'manual' color inside 'aes'. The response above yours is not satisfactory at all - very frequently one needs to overlay density distributions from different sources, not from the same data frame.

Comment: Just to clarify, my solution is, what I would say, the "intended" way of doing this, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38625573/4272484). Using separate geoms (or more than one for each, e.g. a line and scatter plot) for more than 2 different sources would be at least... laborious.

Answer (score 1):

Your data are not formatted correctly and you are basically creating two separate plots on a common "canvas", please see the code below (creation of the `df` is the crucial part):

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  x = c(rnorm(100), runif(100)),
  col = c(rep('blue', 100), rep('red', 100))
)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_density(aes(x = x, color = col)) +
  xlab("Age") + ylab("Density") + ggtitle('Age Densities') + 
  theme(legend.position = 'right') +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c('first', 'second'), values = c('red', 'blue'))
```